# Perl use only an unquoted read-line separator

Tags: perl

I would like the input record separator `$/` to work only outside quoted strings. Here's a concrete example.

I have written a Perl tool that relies on separating lines by semicolons `;` to extract individual C++ statements which can then be handled line-by-line. I have done this with:

```
$/ = ';';
```

Unfortunately it fails in the case that the code has quoted semicolons. For example

```
cout << "I feel it's necessary to separate this message; with a semicolon\n".
```

I can live with a small number of misses, but is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: `Text::ParseWords` may be worth looking at. Or can you split on ";\n" under the assumption that the semicolon will usually be at the end of line?

Comment: Boy, that is a simple and excellent idea that will take me from 1% fail to .001% fail.  I'm smacking my head.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer might be - for most code - assume a 'statement' is a semicolon at end of line. It doesn't have to be though.

However 'doing it right' might be `Text::ParseWords`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Text::ParseWords;

local $/;
my @statements = quotewords( ";", 0, <DATA> );

print Dumper \@statements;

__DATA__
statement; another statement;
statement2; "some text; with a semicolon"; nothing here;
multi
line
statement ;
here
```

This prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'statement',
          ' another statement',
          '
statement2',
          ' some text; with a semicolon',
          ' nothing here',
          '
multi
line
statement ',
          '
here
'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex to find and temporarily replace quoted semicolons with something else.

```
 $_ =~ s/(['"][^;]+)(;)([^;]+['"].*)/$1 QUOTED_SEMI_COLON $3/;
```

After running your script that separates lines at semicolon, QUOTED_SEMI_COLON can be replaced with ';'